# Wix Managed bootstrapper Application: Passing variables to msi through bundle

Tags: c#, wpf, wix, windows-installer

I created a custom UI for my Wix Bundle in WPF with overriding the Bootstrapper Application Class, and I'm struggling with a variable that I need to access and modify if needed from the UI. This variable is the install folder path (string) of the msi deployed by the bootstrapper.

I followed what I found on many forums but It's not working, I can't access this variable. Here is my code:

Msi installer:

```
<Product ...>
  <Feature ...
           ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"
           ...>
</Product>

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="ManufacturerFolder" Name="...">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="!(bind.property.ProductName)"/>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Bundle:

```
<Variable Name="InstallFolder" bal:Overridable="yes" />

<Chain>
      <MsiPackage ...
                  ForcePerMachine="yes"
                  Compressed="no"
                  Visible="no"
                  EnableFeatureSelection="yes"
                  Vital="yes">
        <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
      </MsiPackage>
      ...
</Chain>
```

C# Managed Bootstrapper Application:

```
if (Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables.Contains("InstallFolder"))
  installFolder = Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["InstallFolder"];
```

The "installFolder" variable is always null... I really don't know what is wrong with my code. Hope someone can help me. Thank you

> Edit:
>
> I changed the bundle variable as suggested by Pavel with a default
>   value, now even if I still can't get the value returned by the MSI, I
>   can set Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["InstallFolder"] to a
>   value and it's passed correctly to the msi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey so thanks to Pavel I understand better now how it works:

In the wix bundle, to change an msi variable you need to set a default value, in my case it is:

```
<Variable Name="InstallFolder" Type="string" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" Persisted="yes"/>
```

This default value corresponds to the real default one in the msi. With that I can access this variable from my c# code and change it if needed by doing:

```
Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["InstallFolder"] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember it correctly, Burn variables have numeric type by default.

So, please, try to explicitly specify your variable type. You can also specify the default value:

```
<Variable Name="InstallFolder" Type="string" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]!(bind.packageName.YourMsiPackageId)" Persisted="yes"/>
```

Probably, you should also add Persisted="yes" in order to keep the value if the installer requires reboot in the middle of the installation process.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but I just tried it and it's still not getting the msi variable... I can only get the default value.

Comment: You cannot read the variable from MSI package. Your Burn bootstrapper runs a number of MSI and EXE packages. You can pass the variables from Burn bootstrapper to the packages but not vice versa.

Comment: If you want to read some information in the boostrapper, your MSI package can store it somewhere in the system, e.g. in a registry key. Then you will be able to read it in the bootstrapper using one of standard searches. See http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_define_searches.html for more information

Comment: Oh ok but I need this information during the detection step ? is it possible to store this value in a registry without having to install the msi just by running the bootstrapper ?

Comment: What is your actual workflow? Typically, when we create the bootstrapper, we define some variables with default values in the bootstrapper itself. In the UI of the bootstrapper we can change their values (e.g. installation path) using the Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables property. Later, during Apply phase these variables are passed to the MSI packages. If you simply want to initialize

Comment: If your simply want to use the product name as the default value, you can probably use a linker variable to get it: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/light.html I've update the answer with the example how to do it. Please, replace YourMsiPackageId with your actual package id.

Comment: Thanks a lot I just understood now. So I did like you said I set the default value to [ProgramFilesFolder]!(bind.packageName.YourMsiPackageId) and I get Main.Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["InstallFolder"] = [ProgramFilesFolder]PackageName.

Answer (score 0):

The same question was answered here - [Cannot read input from Bootstrapper variable in Managed Bootstrapper Application C#-Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26012281/cannot-read-input-from-bootstrapper-variable-in-managed-bootstrapper-application)

Short version: you also have to manually parse the command line arguments via `Bootstrapper.Command.GetCommandLineArgs()` and write to the `Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["variable"]`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I saw the link before but when I read the string array returned by GetCommandLineArgs() it's empty..

Comment: Any luck figuring out why it's empty?